# To setup xamarin studio IDE with visual studio community 2017 on Mac machine

Tags: ios, xamarin, vs-community-edition

At run time of xamarin cross platform app i want to access Microsoft SQL server database through Web API(web service) using System.Net.HttpClient. I have developed this xamarin cross platform app on windows 7 using visual studio community. In PCL class library i am not able to add reference of System.Net.HttpClient to access Microsoft sql server database trough web api request. Please give solution to resolve it either on windows system or mac system on which this project build is successful. On MAC machine how can i add reference of System.Net.HttpClient in PCL of xamarin app.

Comment: Please be more specific. What error message are you seeing when you try to add a reference of `System.Net.HttpClient`? Have you tried [Microsoft's Http Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/)? Otherwise you can upgrade to [netstandard](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/net-standard/)

Comment: Hello Jon Douglas, Thanks for your reply. Here is error message detail given below:{System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b0] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.3.0.47/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:879